# add Items to Sencha Nested List

Tags: iphone, list, ipad, nested, extjs

Hi i got a Problem with adding new Items to a Sencha Nested List Component.

currently my code looks like this:

```
var newItem = nestedList.add({text:rowData.name});
nestedList.doLayout();
```

The Problem is the Items just wont show up no matter how often on on what i do call doLayout.
When in debug the nestedList Object, the items are correctly placed in the items array.

Greetings Nexum

Answer (score 1):

try calling nestedlist.update()
thats what i call before dolayout on normal lists

Answer (score 0):

```
nestedList.down("list").add({});
nestedList.down("list").refresh();
```